# Check the last saturday of the current month

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to run a shell script which checks whether today is the last Saturday of the current month and then it runs some script. For eg- 28th is the last Sat of this month.
This is the code I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
DoDay=$(ncal -h | awk ' /Su/ {print $(NF-1)}')
Date=(date +%d)

if [[$Date == $DoDay]]
then 
    echo "Last Saturday"
else 
    echo "not last"
fi
```

While executing, it shows as :

```
ncal:command not found.
```

Can anybody please help here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: On some BSD systems one can use `date -v1d -v+1m -v-1d -v-sat` to get the last Saturday of the month.

Comment: You're missing a $ in `Date=(date +%d)`

Answer (score 2):

GNU date has some text parsing powers that simplyfies this:

```
if test `date +%w` -eq 6 && test "$(date +%m)" -ne "$(date -d 'next saturday' +%m)"; then
    echo "Last Saturday"
else
    echo "not last"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. could you please tell me what does test indicate here?

Comment: test is an utility binary and/or shell internal that does comparisons and returns a true/false return value

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I am running it as a command you could save it in a script and could run it from cron to check it on daily basis too.

```
cal $(date +%m) $(date +%Y) | 
tac | 
awk -v date=$(date +%d) '
  count==1{  exit  }
  NF==7{
    ++count
    if($(NF-1)==date){
      print "Today is last Saturday of month."
      exit
    }
    else{
      print "Today is NOT last Saturday of month."
    }
}'
```

For today's date(its Friday today on 6th Nov 2020) following is the output.

```
Today is NOT last Saturday of month.
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
cal $(date +%m) $(date +%Y) |                       ##Running cal command with passing current month and today date to it
tac |                                               ##Passing cal output to tac command to print it from bottom to top, since we want to read last lines only.
awk -v date=$(date +%d) '                           ##Passing previous output to awk as an Input and create date variable which has today date in it.
  count==1{  exit  }                                ##If count variable is 1 thne exiting from program.
  NF==7{                                            ##Checking condition if number of fields is 7 then do following.
    ++count                                         ##Increasing count with 1 here.
    if($(NF-1)==date){                              ##Checking condition if last field is date then do following.
      print "Today is last Saturday of month."      ##Printing that its last Saturday for this month.
      exit                                          ##exiting from program from here.
    }
    else{                                           ##Else part of above if condition here.
      print "Today is NOT last Saturday of month."  ##printing that its NOT last Saturday of this month.
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU AWK you might harness its [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). I would check it following way:

```
BEGIN{nowtime=systime();nowweekday=strftime("%u",nowtime);nowmonth=strftime("%m",nowtime);nextmonth=strftime("%m",nowtime+604800);if(nowweekday==6 && nowmonth!=nextmonth){print "Last saturday of month"}else{print "Not last saturday of month"}}
```

Explanation: firstly I get current time in terms of seconds since start of epoch, then I get current weekday as number (1-Monday, 7-Sunday), current month as number (1-12) and month of date 7 days later (604800 is number of seconds in 7 days). If today is Saturday and 7 days later will be different month this is last saturday, otherwise it is not, which I print accordingly

Comment: Good idea but you should use noon today to get the seconds since the epoch for today (nowtime) rather than the current actual time today so that when you add on the typical number of seconds in a week later you dont get false results if the current time (or the 1 week later equivalent) was during an hour impacted by a DST transition since that could make your "+ 1 week" calculation end up on a Friday or Sunday instead of the Saturday a week later.

Comment: Please add some whitespace so your code is readable.

Comment: @EdMorton: I must admit I did not take this edge case into consideration

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives to get the last Saturday of the month:

- ncal

  ```sh
  $ ncal | awk '$1 == "Sa" {print $NF}'
  28
  ```
- cal

  ```sh
  $ cal | awk 'NF == 7 {day = $7} END {print day}'
  28
  ```
- GNU date with some shell arithmetic: This uses nested date calls to get the day and day-of-week of the last day of this month, then iterates backwards until the day-of-week is Saturday.

  ```sh
  $ read day dow < <(date -d "$(date  '+%Y-%m-01 +1 month -1 day')" '+%d %w')
  $ while ((dow != 6)); do ((day--)); ((dow = (dow - 1 + 7) % 7)); done
  $ echo $day
  28
  ```